# Why does WinSCP log "Proxy: None" when I've told it to use Tor (sftp)?

Tags: windows, proxy, sftp, winscp

```
2019-10-04 16:35:44.076 Switch:    /ini=nul
2019-10-04 16:35:44.076 Switch:    /ProxyMethod=2
2019-10-04 16:35:44.076 Switch:    /ProxyHost=127.0.0.1
2019-10-04 16:35:44.076 Switch:    /ProxyPort=9150
2019-10-04 16:35:44.076 Switch:    /loglevel=2
2019-10-04 16:35:44.076 Proxy: None
```

I literally feed it `/ProxyMethod=2 /ProxyHost=127.0.0.1 /ProxyPort=9150` and it even acknowledges it in the log (as you can see above), yet also logs "**Proxy: None**". What does that mean? Does it use the proxy (Tor) or not? What does it mean by "**Proxy: None**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I literally feed it `/ProxyMethod=2 /ProxyHost=127.0.0.1 /ProxyPort=9150`

But that's a wrong syntax. WinSCP just logs all parameters it gets, it does not mean that they are correct.

The correct syntax is to use when with your `open` command:

```
open <url> /rawsettings ProxyMethod=2 ProxyHost=127.0.0.1 ProxyPort=9150
```

WinSCP GUI can [generate a correct script template for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script).

See also the [example for raw session settings use](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings#example).

Comment: Thanks. Confusing syntax. It now does say "Proxy: SOCKS5" in the log... but I still can't connect. Even with a graphical SFTP client (through Tor). Probably just blocked or something... although that's worrying in terms of it working with the non-test, production SFTP server...

Comment: Clarification: When I use the proxy (Tor), it actually *does* download the text file, just as the WinSCP script says, so it obviously *does* work... but WinSCP returns status code "1", meaning "error"... the log doesn't give any clues as to why that happens. Really weird.

Comment: The syntax is as it is documented. + If you want help with the exit code, please post a new question and include a session log file.